# R, get column names, reshaping

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I'm trying to reshape wide DB to long. I want to get all column names and make them to the year column. How can I get all column names from 1961 to 2016

```
nsoil <- melt(soil, id.vars = c("CountryName", "Country.Code"),
              measure.vars = c(colnames("1961"......."2016")),
              variable.name = "years"
              value.name = "%AgroLands"
              )
nsoil
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `1961:2016` perhaps?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimally reproducible example of your data? It will help others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oh Jeez, that easy, thanks